# How to programmatically set the disabled state color for a qt control?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

In the load event of my window, I am accessing the `rootObject()` (which is a `QQuickItem`) and using that to get a reference to controls defined in my QML file. I am then using this code to programmatically set/change the control's color:

```
object->setProperty("color", "#3060C0");
```

This works and does change the control to the color I want. However, if the control is disabled and then re-enabled at run time, it then shows the default color (black) instead of the color `#3060C0`. If I set the `color:` property in the QML file, it "sticks" and retains this color even after being disabled and re-enabled, but I need to be able to change this color programmatically.

Is there some way to programmatically set the disabled-state color in addition to the regular "color" property like I'm doing? Or some way to disable the color change with the enabled property change entirely?

Comment: To be honest I would bet that it's just a bug.. which Qt version you are using?

Comment: @evilruff: qt 5.5.1 and Qt Creator 3.6.1

Comment: There may also be some custom code or qml logic elsewhere in the app that is hooked into the enabled state change and is setting the color there. I've inherited this app and don't fully understand it (or Qt) very well yet.

Comment: So, has the issue been resolved? :)
As it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this from C++, that's simply wrong. Don't develop bad practices.

> If I set the color: property in the QML file, it "sticks" and retains
>   this color even after being disabled and re-enabled, but I need to be
>   able to change this color programmatically.

There is a simple and easy way to do this in QML, where it should be done:

```
color: enabled ? colEnabled : colDisabled
```

You can use expressions in bidings, and when the expressions include properties which notify of changes, this causes the expression to automatically reevaluate every time its components change. So every time `enabled` changes, the proper color will be assigned depending on whether `enabled` is true or false.

You can also write more complex expressions, not just single liners, you can write the expression as:

```
color: {
    if (enabled) return colEnabled 
    else return colDisabled
}
```

Also pay attention between assignment and binding. If you assign `color = someColor` that will break the existing binding. You can also set bindings in "imperative" code:

`color = Qt.binding(function() { ...bla bla... })`